# How to identify a vegan supplement?

Tags: veganism, vitamins-and-minerals, supplements, labeling

If I am considering supplements to balance my dietary intake, how do I identify if they are vegan?

To clarify, if I have altered my diet to eliminate eating animals, how can I be sure that my supplements are not from animal sources?

Answer (score 6):

If you're just buying at the supermarket, you really can't know.  There are lots of [hidden animal products](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/36/hidden-non-vegetarian-or-vegan-ingredients/47#47), especially in supplements.

My advice would be to purchase them online from an [all vegan website](http://www.veganstore.com/category/individual-and-multi).  That way you'll know they're vegan.  Otherwise make sure the supplement specifically says vegan on it.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the question would be largely the same as for identifying vegan anything.

First, **look for the vegan label on the package**. Usually this is either a nice green V, even nicer animal picture or, as Zanna suggested, [this logo](http://welearntoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/VeganTMLogo_col_shad-300x248.jpg). Make sure this does not mean Suitable for vegetarians as this still may (and probably will) not be vegan.

If you could not find the label anywhere, your Spidey-sense should start tingling and you should **read the packaging carefully**. Have a look at the contents - is there **anything highlighted in bold**? Are there mentioned **obscure things that you do not know what they are** and they are not why you are buying the product? Is the description mentioning that the product is **suitable for *vegetarians***? If any of this is true, do not buy, do your thorough research, check online to see what others say, generally make sure.

If after all this you did not reach a definite conclusion, **write to the company that sells the product**.

Somewhere along the way, you should find out whether what you are buying is vegan.

Comment: You can look for the [Vegan Society logo](http://welearntoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/VeganTMLogo_col_shad-300x248.jpg) in some countries

Comment: Added that to the answer. I forgot about the sunflower one, thanks :).