# What non-vegetarian and/or non-vegan ingredients can be found in cosmetics?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan, is-it-vegetarian, cosmetics

Veganism is [defined](https://www.vegansociety.com/go-vegan/definition-veganism) as "a way of living which **seeks to exclude, as far as is possible and practicable, all forms of exploitation of, and cruelty to, animals for food, clothing or any other purpose**". As vegans, it follows that we should avoid all animal by-products (as well as animal testing) in cosmetics.

Previous questions have only dealt with [hidden ingredients in food labels](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/36/hidden-non-vegetarian-or-vegan-ingredients) or [particular ingredients in cosmetics](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmetics).

[Carmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmine#Production) is probably the best-known example of a by-product used in cosmetics, as it's also used as a food colorant.

**What are other animal derivatives commonly used in the production of makeup and personal hygiene products?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cosmetics are very complex products (lots of different substances) and it is quite hard to really understand if one product is 100% vegan or not.

[This article](https://www.plantbasednews.org/opinion/14-non-vegan-ingredients-to-look-out-for-in-make-up-and-beauty-products) touches the surface of some non-vegan substances that are used for cosmetics:

- **Lanolin** as emollient
- **Shellac** in nail or hair products
- **Glycerine** is used for a broad range of products that include soaps, hair care, make-up, and moisturizers
- **Casein** in hair or face treatments products
- **Squalene**
- **Guanine** for providing spark for various products such as nail polish, eyeshadow etc.
- **Oleic acid** for a moisturizing effect
- **Stearic Acid**
- **Carmine** for the natural red color
- **Collagen** promoted as having an anti-aging effect

As a side note, I also recommend reading [this article](https://www.science.org.au/curious/people-medicine/chemistry-cosmetics) which provides a great insight into the chemistry of cosmetics. Besides the rather complex chemical cocktail of many cosmetics, what is worse is that not all ingredients are put on the label:

> Chemicals, both natural and synthetic, are added to cosmetics to
> provide an appealing fragrance. Even ‘unscented’ products may contain
> masking fragrances to mask the smell of other chemicals.
>
> The term ‘fragrance’ is often a generic term used by manufacturers. A
> single listing of fragrance on your product’s ingredient list could
> represent dozens or even hundreds of unlisted chemical compounds that
> were used to create the final individual fragrance.
>
> Manufacturers do not have to list these individual ingredients as
> fragrance is considered to be a **trade secret**.